# Passing a object to my test case from mainthread using unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

i am new to python and just now started developing an linux application automation.

scenario i am trying is

thread.py --- will invoke all primary device threads and load test from testcase

admincase.py --- hold my tests for the case..

what i am unable to do is i want to pass certain objects from thread.py to admincase.py when loading the test. how do i do that..

object which i am tryin to pass is (**EppQueue**)

thread.py code

```
import threading
import sys
import time
import logging
import os
import Queue
from EPP import EPP
import ldtp
import ldtputils
from functions import functions
from admincases import admincases
import unittest

#logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
#                    format='(%(threadName)-10s) %(message)s',
#                    )
class inittest(unittest.TestCase):
    global fun
    global EppQueue
    global window_name

    def cleanup(epp_port):
        if os.path.exists(epp_port):
            os.unlink(epp_port)

    def start_threads(EppQueue,server_ip,epp_port):
        epp = EPP
        EPP1 = threading.Thread(name='EPP', target=epp, args=(server_ip,54321,epp_port,EppQueue,))
        EPP1.setDaemon(True)
        EPP1.start()
        return epp 
    fun = functions()
    EppQueue = Queue.Queue(1)
    server_ip ='192.168.10.125'
    epp_port='/dev/ttyS17'
    print "Starting"
    cleanup(epp_port)
    print "Clean up Over"
    epp = start_threads(EppQueue,server_ip,epp_port)
    raw_input("###### Please Start the main appilcation in the ATM and hit a KEY to continue ############")
    check = 0
    while check == 0:
        window_name = fun.start_up_verify('atm_main_app')
        if any(window_name):
            check = 1
        else:
            check = 0
    if not any(window_name):
        print "Please start the application and run the test"
        sys.exit(0) 
    else:
        print window_name
        print "SYSTEM IS READY TO PERFORM TEST"
        raw_input("###### HIT ANY KEY TO START UNIT TEST ############")
        raw_input("kkk")    
        test = unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromName("admincases")
        unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(test)
    raw_input("keyy")
    print "final"
```

admincase.py code

```
import unittest
from functions import functions
import time
import Queue

class admincases(unittest.TestCase):
    global fun
    global EppQueue
    global window_name

    def test_case_1(self):
        print "test case 1"
        window_name = 'frmatm_main_app'
        fun.send_queue(self.EppQueue,"send_keys,&&&&&")
        fun.verify_screen(window_name,"ico0") 
        fun.send_queue(self.EppQueue,"send_keys,C")
        fun.verify_screen(window_name,"ManagementFunctions") 
        fun.send_queue(self.EppQueue,"send_keys,001234")
        fun.verify_screen(window_name,"MainMenu")
        fun.send_queue(self.EppQueue,"send_keys,1")
        fun.verify_screen(window_name,"Diagnostics")
        fun.send_queue(self.EppQueue,"send_keys,1")
        fun.verify_screen(window_name,"TerminalStatus")
        fun.send_queue(self.EppQueue,"send_keys,2")
        time.sleep(10)
        fun.send_queue(self.EppQueue,"send_keys,####****")


    fun = functions()
    #EppQueue = Queue.Queue(1)
```

Need some assistance on this...